# WebGL / Box2D drawing issue: gap between bodies

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, box2d, webgl

I'm still a graphics programming novice and bet the following problem is just a matter of wrong configuration.

i am creating a game using webgl for graphics and box2dweb for physics. unfortunately the drawing shows gaps between the physical bodies (left is my actual rendering, right is a rendering using box2dweb's debug-drawing in another canvas):

[image]

both box2d and webgl use the same coordinate-system and sizes for the boxes. there is no conversion. the red boxes are actually textures, though this doesn't make a difference. the red boxes are dynamic bodies, the green boxes are static bodies.

obviously i can't just resize graphics or physics. if i made the graphics bigger, the green boxes would overlap, if made physics smaller there will be physics-gaps.

here is another example:

[image]

also, sometimes, there there is no gap  just like in the following (just moved the physic-bodies a little on the right)

[image]

the black boxes are just color-drawn (no textures). looking at the previous image, i guess it has to do with converting the floating-world-coordinates to screen-pixel-coordinates, but i have no idea what the option for fixing this would be.

Thanks a lot for the help

**[Update]**

It is an ortographic projection matrix, that I am initializing in the following way:

```
mat4.ortho(-this.vpWidth * this.zoom, this.vpWidth * this.zoom, -this.vpHeight * this.zoom, this.vpHeight * this.zoom, 0.1, 100.0, this.pMatrix);
```

vpWidth and vpHeight are the canvas-dimensions (640 * 480). the projection matrix is passed to the vertex-shader and multiplied with the model-view-matrix and the vertex-position. i played around with the zoom-factor. the more i zoom in the bigger the gaps are.

**[Update 2]**

okay. i investigated this a little more. bad zeppelin had a good hint. **box2d has gaps between bodies to avoid tunneling**. though this is not the complete explanation. i looked at the debug-draw-code - it is not resizing anything. i made a little test, zooming in both in webgl and for the debug draw with the following result:

[image]

with 10-times-zoom both have the same gap, but in "normal" zoom webgl is drawing bigger gaps than canvas 2d. what could be the explanation? my guess is **anti-aliasing**, which is enabled for canvas 2d, but not for webgl (i am using firefox - guess i'll make a chrome test later today to see what happens)

Comment: I think we're going to need a bit more information before we can help. My first impression is that you've got an Orthographic projection matrix that doesn't match up with your canvas dimensions. Could you give us a little bit more detail about your scene set up?

Comment: i updated the post a bit. it is indeed an orthographic projection. thanks.

Comment: related https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15092/rectangles-render-with-gaps-in-between-them-box2d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [box2d manual](http://box2d.org/manual.pdf), it says on the chapter 4.2 that the box2d engine keeps the polygons slightly separated to avoid tunneling. Checking the Box2d debug drawing code to see how they translate from box2d to draw coordinates might be a good idea to see how you could do the same in your app.

Comment: very good hint! this is true, though it doesn't solve the whole mystery. the gap-size depends on zoom-level. i updated my question with more information. thanks a lot!

Comment: According to the same document, polygon shapes inherit the radius field from the shape class. And that creates the gap between shapes. You can use this value and draw your shapes slightly bigger.

Answer (score 0):

With the matrix you provided, you'll be creating a viewport that has a "virtual size" of twice your canvas dimensions. If you are trying for a pixel-for-pixel match, try this (with a zoom of 1.0):

```
mat4.ortho(-(this.vpWidth/2) * this.zoom, (this.vpWidth/2) * this.zoom, -(this.vpHeight/2) * this.zoom, (this.vpHeight/2) * this.zoom, 0.1, 100.0, this.pMatrix);
```

That way your 640*480 canvas will have extents of [-320,-240] to [320*240], which gives you 640*480 units total. Note that this will probably not eliminate the gaps entirely, since as bad zeppelin noted box2d puts them there intentionally, but it should make them less visible.

Another option to reduce the visible gaps is to draw your geometry scaled up just a bit from the physical representation, so that it displays with an extra pixel or two around the edges. The worst that may happen is that the geometry might appear to overlap just a bit, but it's up to you to determine if that's a more objectionable artifact than the gaps.